# How can I add / download web development settings to my existing Visual Studio installation?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

When Visual Studio 2010 (10.0.4 SP1) was installed on my machine, it seems no web development settings were installed. There are no web projects under templates, and Web Development Settings do not appear under the default settings list (Under Tools->Import Export Settings).

I don't know for sure that I'm not just missing some big obvious 'Switch to Web Development Mode' button somewhere, but I've had a good Google and a look and I cant see anything.

I would rather not have to install Visual Web Developer. Is there some way I can add web development settings to my existing install of Visual Studio?

Comment: What version of Visual Studio?

Comment: @jadarnel27 2010. Version 10.0.4 SP1

Comment: Cool, thanks for the info.  I've updated your tags and title slightly.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps to install it while installing Web Deploymnet Settings

·        Insert the DVD or CDROM Disk 1 – the Setup program starts automatically.

·        Click Install Visual Studio 2010 and follow the instructions.

o   This installs Visual Studio, the .NET framework, the development web server, and SQL Server 2008 Express.

o   If you are installing Visual Web Developer 2010 Express Edition, it does NOT install SQL Server 2008 Express – you’ll need to download SQL Server 2008 and install it separately.

·        On the Options page accept Default option – for the Default Environment Settings you can select Web Development Settings.

·        Click the Install Product Documentation link to install the MSDN help files.

You must have missed it so run the setup again and as you don't want to reinstall VS you'll be asked to repair the setup there you can select the feature

refer:http://www.siue.edu/~dbock/cmis460/Module%20A%20--%20Appendix%20A%20in%20textbook/ModuleA-InstallSoftware.htm

Comment: I don't have a CD, and systems are not willing to provide me with one. Large downloads are frowned upon so I don't want to just DL the image. I was hoping for a solution that did not require the original install files.

Comment: So you are saying that this is not in any way possible? What makes you sure? Without trying to be rude, I don't want to waste time on this if this isn't possible, but I also don't wan't to waste time downloading and reinstalling if you are just making an educated guess if you see what I mean.

Comment: Having had a closer look unfortunately this is not at all what I am looking for. That is just an addon that makes 2008/2005 web projects compatible with 2010.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.microsoft.com/web/gallery/install.aspx?appid=VWDorVS2010SP1Pack

This adds the web development parts to an installed version of visual studio that lacks them (along with all the other tool you require for web development)